# How can I rewrite URLs by removing a part of it with regex?

Tags: regex, apache

I have a series of URLs like this:

```
https://pocketnews.it/folder/subfolder/1234-rqoiryiewoqryiuewoqyroiwqhfkjlahflkdjsa
```

and I need to remove a part of it that which changes slightly between different URLs, like the following:

```
folder/subfolder/1234-
folder3/subfolder2/32456-
folder3/subfolder3/1234-
```

To obtain URLs like this one:

```
https://pocketnews.it/rqoiryiewoqryiuewoqyroiwqhfkjlahflkdjsa
```

I thought about using regex in the rewrite rules like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^pocketnews.it\/(.*)[-]$ http://pocketnews.it/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't work

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: `Rewrit­eCond %{HTTP­_HOST} ^pocketnews\.it$ [NC]` and then `Rewrit­eRule ^.*-(.*)$ http://pocketnews.it/$1 [R=301,L]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)[-](.*)$ https://pocketnews.it/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Some sites helps with regexp, like https://regexr.com/